# Using an .htaccess file with WordPress and an htm site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a normal website in html and have added a WordPress installation. I have a    .htaccess file with

```
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
# END WordPress
```

This all works fine except I have a script in sitename.com/general/article/index.php which only works if there is no htaccess file, otherwise it shows a 404 or "Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@sitename.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have no real idea what I am doing, so thought somebody here could help me get it to work.